# Conda uninstall package from Environment PackagesNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, tensorflow2.0

`conda list` shows that `tensorflow` is installed in the environment but when trying to uninstall it gives `PackagesNotFoundError`.

`Conda list` results: 
[image]
[image]

`sudo conda uninstall tensorflow` result:

[image]

Can you please help me to overcome this?

Comment: In future, please consider posting all text data in code-blocks instead of images. Images makes it harder for us to help you. That said, why are you using sudo for uninstalling but not for the conda list command? What happens if you leave sudo out?

Comment: Sure, will do in a future post, Thanks for the suggestion. if i drop `sudo` i get the following error : EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same issue on Windows. I ended up locating the package via `package.__path__` and removing it manually:

#### Initial state

Without administrator permissions:

```
C:\Users\felix>conda list cumulator
# packages in environment at C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cumulator                 0.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi

C:\Users\felix>conda remove cumulator
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - cumulator
```

With administrator permissions:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda list cumulator
# packages in environment at C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cumulator                 0.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi

C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda remove cumulator
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - cumulator
```

#### Solution

Locating the package:

```
C:\Users\felix>python
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 09:42:29) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cumulator
>>> cumulator.__path__
['C:\\Users\\felix\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\cumulator']
>>> exit()
```

I navigated to `site-packages` and removed both `cumulator` and `cumulator-0.0.7.dist-info` directories.

#### Result

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

Problem solved!